# Can't able to embed javascript code into a Android webview?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I want to embed javascript code into original facebook page.But I got the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

Pls help me.This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String email="qwerty@xyz.com";
            String password="1234";
            String javaScript="javascript:(function(){ document.getElementById('email').value='"+email+
                    "';document.getElementById('pass').value='"+password+
                    "';document.getElementById('u_0_a').click();})()";
            view.loadUrl(javaScript);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");

}
```

}

Comment: It's running.  `document.getElementById('pass')` is returning undefined.

Comment: Yeah Bro But I got that error how to clear that bro.

Comment: There is nothing in the page with that Id.  Fix that problem, fix *the* problem.

Comment: But I have that Id field in that page.

Comment: No you don't.  You run the javascript and *then* you load Facebook.  Do it the other way around, and wait until the page has loaded before you run your script.

Comment: Ok Bro.I got that.Thanks bro